# Is there any way that Cognito Forms can display calculations only?

Tags: email, cognito-forms

I created a form with Cognito Forms, taking advantage from calculation function. Is there any chance in email I can get only the fields with calculation rather than fields with data entered.

Answer (score 1):

I work with support for Cognito Forms.  To include just the fields you want, you can go into the email settings for the Notification or Confirmation emails.  Click on the Message field and then look in the Toolbar for "Insert Fields".  From there, you can craft your email to have only the fields you want.

You may also want to turn off "Include Entry Details" on the email setting so that the entry fields aren't included.  Otherwise you will get the fields you entered in the Message field and then also get any other fields with data.